# What is the benefit of using CGPath?

Tags: objective-c, ios, bezier, cgpath

I am new to CGPath concept and have a decent idea about Bezier curves.
I am creating a small free hand drawing program using a View.
In drawRect I keep drawing recorded set of lines from an Array.
and while my mouse moves I add a new line to that array and refresh the view.
drawrect is called again and it draws the recorded set of lines again.

I was reading about CGPath, it says that internally it does something similar to what I am doing.
storing a set of lines and Bezier curves.

So is there any performance improvement, if I use CGPath ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answer your question about CGPath.

> You might not want to lose your path so easily, especially if it
>   depicts a complex scene you want to use over and over again. For that
>   reason, Quartz provides two data types for creating reusable
>   paths CGPathRef and CGMutablePathRef.

Reference in section creating a path.
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-SW1

Comment: It doesn't answer my question completely.

Comment: There is some performance gain if you reuse the CGPath such as stroking and filling the path. For example, without using CGPath such as just use CGContextStrokePath,  "Quartz uses the line width and stroke color of the graphics state to paint the path. As a side effect when you call this function, Quartz clears the current path." -- Apple iOS SDK documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems I will have to get used to goin thru the documentation a lot :)